# How to change placing of block to another page?

Tags: magento, checkout

I have a Gift Card extension. I have to change placing of it.

Like this

[image]

I have purchase this from Magestore.

Block call giftvoucher/payment/form.phtml

So I need this block call into checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

Thank you

Comment: Find the template file that render those codes and place it anywhere you need. That is the easiest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block you want to shift, if it contains only Static content. Then you can use the following code within **payment.phtml**

```
<?php print $this->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock("core/template")
                 ->setTemplate("[FILE_PATH_FOR_STATIC_CONTENT].phtml")
                 ->toHtml(); ?>
```

You can also put this content into Static Block using Admin which also makes you enable you to change its content anytime.

Call Static block within PHTML file -

```
 <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("cms/block")->setBlockId("STATIC_BLOCK_NAME")->toHtml() ?>
```